# How can I remove part of URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, mod-rewrite

I have a link `https://example.com/src/index.php`, and want `index.php`, and other pages, which are in `src` folder, to be accessible without `src` in the URL.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is your existing `.htaccess` file an attempt at a solution? Those directives (although incorrect) would imply you are implementing extensionless URLs, although this is not stated in your question?

Comment: Those directives are for another purposes, I know. It's not my solution, I just wanted to show an existing .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
# Serve file from "/src" subdirectory if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/src/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^.+\.\w{2,4}$ src/$0 [L]
```

If you request `/index.php` and this file exists at `/src/index.php` then it will internally rewrite the request to that subdirectory.

The regex `^.+\.\w{2,4}$` matches only files (ie. URLs that include a file extension).

`$0` is a backreference to the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

If a file happened to exist in both places then the file in the `/src` subdirectory would take priority.